# Navigation Drawer without custom toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-components-android

I had implemented **Navigation Drawer with fragments** which is totally working fine. Now I want to implement Navigation Drawer without using custom Toolbar (with **AppTheme== DarkActionbar**). I am not able to do such without having custom toolbar. I had already go through many blogs and tutorials but can't get desire solution.

If there is anyone can help me for solving my problem than it will be very helpful to me.

**Note**: I am not using Navigation Controller for This, I am using Old method which is to add Drawer and DrawerActiobarToogle etc.

Comment: You can start using a `.NoActionBar` theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to put away with ActionBar, like @GabrieleMariotti suggests, you can use any of ***.NoActionBar** themes.

Or, if you have already known about theme and want to use NavigationUI without Toolbar, there is a way.

In your MainActivity's onCreate:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

You can setup the navigationView like above. That's all. And don't setup appBarConfiguration like below:

```
drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
    R.id.fragment1, R.id.fragment2, R.id.fragment3
).setOpenableLayout(drawer).build();
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

For you don't want toolbar, this is needless.

Without hamburger button, you can still open the drawer by swiping. If you want to have a hamburger button, place a button on the layout which is set onClickListener to open the drawer.

```
FloatingActionButton fabNavigation = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_navigation);
fabNavigation.setOnClickListener(view1 -> onClick());
```

Drawer opener method example:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is helpful for me.Navigation Controller is the solution of my Problem and its fine. but what if we are working with an old method instead of using controller ?

Comment: @HarshPatel Without NavigationUI, you will use `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);` and implement NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener in which you define to replace a Fragment with FragmentManager.